# Took out 1 Torah instead of 2 - What should be done?

Tags: torah-reading

The shul has small ark. On Shabbat Chanukah one year, the gabbai placed one Torah in the ark before minyan began, and it seems that with a mainly "secular" congregation (I.e., the 15 people that formed the minyan), no one else realized that on Shabbat Chanukah you need 2 Sifrei Torah.

They read the weekly portion (Miketz), say Kaddish, and just before hagbah, the gabbai realizes that they should have had two Sifrei Torah! But the other Torah is in another room in another wing of the shul. It would actually be quicker to just roll the current Torah from Miketz to the Chanukah portion than get another Torah.

Should they roll this Torah, as it is less of a *tircha detzibbur*, or do they still need to get the 2nd Torah from the other room?

**Note:** - The story is an example. The answer should be general to any situation where multiple Sifrei Torah are needed, having the same situation, but on a different occasion.

Comment: You've explained why it might be preferable to roll the Torah. Do you have a reason why it might be preferable to get a different _sefer_?

Comment: @Daniel There was a MY question similar to this (may have been related to Shabbat Rosh Hodesh Hachodesh - I have to hunt for it, (B"N after Shabbat) that says that in some cases (don't recall exact scenario), one should take out an extra Torah because it is important to show the congregation that there is an extra reading and that the day is important. I'll try to find that question, as I asked it, myself some time ago.